# Meaning of port in Eclipse debug view

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

In the Eclipse debug view:

[image]

what is the meaning of the `localhost:51883`? Is it the connection port for remote debugging? or is something else?

Comment: It's a port where you submit all your HTTP requests

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I'm connecting to this application through port 8080

Comment: @PradeepSimha : It is not the port at which ___you submit all your HTTP requests___

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is the port using which Eclipse debugger communicates to the Virtual Machine. 
VM has got a JPDA (Java Platform Debugger Architecture) that provide interfaces (JVM TI - Java VM Tool Interface,  JDI - Java Debug Interface) that tools like eclipse debugger use to connect and debug. And the port they connect onto is shown in that view.

You see, in this case your VM is on your localhost so it shows localhost:51883 , in case you were into remotedebugging, it would show `serverIP:availableport`

Answer (score 1):

The eclipse debugger communicates with the VM via TPC, using this port. It works like remote debugging, but it connects on localhost.